# É possível multiplicar uma variavel do tipo "factor"?

Tags: r, dplyr, factors

Estou trabalhando com o seguinte banco de dados: [qualis.capes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hpanqdcflmt7bd/EXEMPLO.xlsx?dl=0)

Eu importo esse banco de dados usando o `rio::import()` e gravo no objeto "df". E carrego `library(dplyr)`

Resultado:

```
library(dplyr)
df<-rio::import("EXEMPLO.xlsx")
head(df)

  ordem  ano qualis.ref
1     1 2017         B1
2     2 2017         B4
3     3 2017         NP
4     4 2017         A3
5     5 2017         B4
6     6 2017         B1
```

Acontece que os valores da variável "qualis.ref" correspondem a pesos. Conforme a seguinte equivalência:

A1=1,0

A2=0,8

A3=0,7

A4=0,6

B1=0,5

B2=0,35

B3=0,2

B4=0,1

C=0

NP=0

O que estou tentando fazer é obter a pontuação, por ano, de cada "qualis.ref"

Para tanto, eu primeiro converto a variável "qualis.ref" em fator usando a função `factor()`:

```
df$qualis.ref<-as.factor(df$qualis.ref)
```

Depois eu crio uma nova variável chamada "peso", que é uma cópia de "qualis.ref":

```
peso<-df$qualis.ref
```

Para então atribuir VALORES conforme a equivalência citada acima:

```
levels(peso)<-c(1, 0.85, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.35, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0)
```

Em seguida, junto tudo em um novo data.frame chamado "df2" usando a função `cbind()`:

```
df2<-cbind(df, peso)

  ordem  ano qualis.ref peso
1     1 2017         B1  0.5
2     2 2017         B4  0.1
3     3 2017         NP    0
4     4 2017         A3  0.7
5     5 2017         B4  0.1
6     6 2017         B1  0.5
```

Por fim, agrupo usando a função `group_by()` e peço para fazer a contagem do "qualis.ref" com a função `count()`.

É aí que surge meu problema, usei a função `mutate()` para criar uma nova coluna chamada "pontuacao" na perspectiva de que eu pudesse multiplicar a quantidade de "qualis.ref" contados por seus respectivos pesos.

Ficou assim:

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(ano, qualis.ref, peso) %>%
  count(qualis.ref) %>% 
  mutate(pontuacao=peso*n)

# A tibble: 40 x 5
# Groups:   ano, qualis.ref, peso [40]
     ano qualis.ref peso      n pontuacao
   <dbl> <fct>      <fct> <int> <lgl>    
 1  2017 A1         1         4 NA       
 2  2017 A2         0.85      8 NA       
 3  2017 A3         0.7      26 NA       
 4  2017 A4         0.6       4 NA       
 5  2017 B1         0.5      39 NA       
 6  2017 B2         0.35     10 NA       
 7  2017 B3         0.2       3 NA       
 8  2017 B4         0.1       9 NA       
 9  2017 C          0        14 NA       
10  2017 NP         0        10 NA       
# ... with 30 more rows
There were 40 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

No entanto, toda a variável "pontuacao" aparece com "NA".

O que me leva a pensar que o problema é com a variável do tipo "fator".

Testei com uma variável do tipo "double" a partir do "mtcars" e a multiplicação funcionou. Multipliquei as variáveis "gear" e "carb":

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(teste=gear*carb) %>% 
  head()

   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb teste
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    16
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    16
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     4
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     3
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2     6
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1     3
```

Comment: Não, não é possível operar variáveis do tipo `factor`
recomendo [essa leitura](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r)

Comment: Como é que é possível uma pergunta ter 2 votos contra e uma resposta com 5 votos a favor? A resposta pode ser útil para outros mas a pergunta não?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma variável da classe factor é um conjunto de valores e de rótulos, os levels. Essa classe serve então para armazenar dados categóricos, não fazendo sentido operações como multiplicação com ela.

Em `levels(peso)<-c(1, 0.85, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.35, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0)` foi mudar os rótulos dos dados e não uma transformação do tipo de dados. Então você manteve os dados como categorias só que com nomes diferentes pra elas.

```
peso
[1] 0.85 0.7  0.6  1    0.7  0.85
Levels: 1 0.85 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.35 0.2 0.1 0
```

O seu código você consegue consertar transformando os fatores primeiro em character, para acessar os rótulos, e depois em numeric, para transformar eles em números.

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(ano, qualis.ref, peso) %>%
  count(qualis.ref) %>% 
  mutate(pontuacao=as.numeric(as.character(peso))*n)
```

Entretanto o que sugiro é fazer a transformação de outra maneira, sem envolver a criação do factor. Eu utilizei os dados que você deu para criar um dicionário dos valores e com eles você pode fazer a transformação diretamente.

```
valores <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "C", "NP")
dicionario <- setNames(c(1, 0.85, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.35, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0), valores)

df %>% 
  mutate(peso = dicionario[qualis.ref]) %>% 
  group_by(ano, qualis.ref, peso) %>% 
  count(qualis.ref) %>% 
  mutate(pontuacao = peso*n)
```